# i want to terminate the app after some minutes while it run in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i want to terminate the app  after some minutes while it runs in background.

steps like  these :

press the  home  button  then  app  run in background.
2minutes later the app terminates automaticly.

i find a method as below:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UIApplication*    app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Do the work associated with the task.

           //============================
          // here  i want to add a timer  
          //=============================  

        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}
```

as you see,
i want to  add a timer  in that place.

but the timer didn't work in background. i also tried the performSelector:afterdelay:

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

After 10 minutes, All app terminates.

If you have to exit app only after 2 mins,

set timer in (applicationWillResignActive)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your app is doing some kind of work while in background - otherwise there would be no need to run it in the background in the first place.

I further suppose you have some kind of runloop going, since you'd like to terminate after a certain amount of time and not after some task has been completed.

So I'd suggest logging the system time at the moment the app goes into background and then in your runloop check for the current system time once per iteration. If it is greater than the initial time + 2 minutes, terminate background activity.

Comment: Sorry. Your sopposition is wrong...   In fact nothing work in background. I just do want a task that can do some work in background.  But,when app goes to back,nothing can work.